# Active Brownian Motion

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I am attempting to write a Python code to simulate many particles in a confined box. These particles behave in such a way that they move in the box in straight lines with a slight angular noise (small changes in the direction of the particle path). They should interact by acknowledging the other particle and 'shuffle/squeeze' past each other and continue on their intended path, much like humans on a busy street. Eventually, the particles should cluster together when the density of particles (or packing fraction) reaches a certain value, but I haven't got to this stage yet.

The code currently has particle interactions and I have attempted the angular noise but without success so far. The problems I would like some help with are the angular noise and the particle interactions. My idea for the angular noise was to multiply the data by a number between roughly 0.9 and 1.1 to change the direction of the particle slightly but after adding the lines in, nothing changed. The particles do interact but they seem to move in a fast semi-circle around the other interacting which is not what I want.
I don't think any knowledge or understanding of ABM is needed to write the angular noise code but some may be needed for the forces, I am not 100% sure though.

If anyone has any improvements for the code speed or ideas which may help with the interactions and/or angular noise that would be much appreciated. I will also leave an example of an animation which is my aim: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/staff/research/cwhitfield/abpsimulations

The above link shows the animation I am looking for, although I don't need the sliders, just the box, and moving particles. The whole code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def set_initial_coordinates():
    x_co = [np.random.uniform(0, 2) for i in range(n_particles)]
    y_co = [np.random.uniform(0, 2) for i in range(n_particles)]
    return x_co, y_co


def set_initial_velocities():
    x_vel = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(n_particles)])
    y_vel = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1, 1) for i in range(n_particles)])
    return x_vel, y_vel


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-0.05, 2.05)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.07, 2.07)
    return ln,


def update(dt):
    xdata = initialx + vx * dt
    ydata = initialy + vy * dt
    fx = np.abs((xdata + 2) % 4 - 2)
    fy = np.abs((ydata + 2) % 4 - 2)

    for i in range(n_particles):
        for j in range(n_particles):
            if i == j:
                continue

            dx = fx[j] - fx[i]  # distance in x direction
            dy = fy[j] - fy[i]  # distance in y direction
            dr = np.sqrt((dx ** 2) + (dy ** 2))  # distance between x

            if dr <= r:
                force = k * ((2 * r) - dr)  # size of the force if distance is less than or equal to radius

                # Imagine a unit vector going from i to j
                x_comp = dx / dr  # x component of force
                y_comp = dy / dr  # y component of force

                fx[i] += -x_comp * force  # x force
                fy[i] += -y_comp * force  # y force
    ln.set_data(fx, fy)
    return ln,


# theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2) for i in range(n_particles)
n_particles = 10
initialx, initialy = set_initial_coordinates()
vx, vy = set_initial_velocities()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_co, y_co = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'bo', markersize=15)  # radius 0.05
plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 2)

k = 1
r = 0.1
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, t, init_func=init, blit=True, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem. However, I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better suited for this.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Yeah that is a good point, I have posted this problem there too but from past experience, they often prefer to see code that functions and needs optimising/improving/sped up rather than fixing problems that currently do not work. I am never sure whether to use the code review or Overflow so I have tried both. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: are u sure about `force = k * ((2 * r) - dr)` ? This formula results in discontinuous function at `dr==r`? This may make solution unstable.

Comment: Thanks for the question @tstanisl, the force is supposed to similar to a spring force, for example F=-kx where x is the displacement and k is the spring constant. I should point out that in this case, r is the radius of the circle and dr is the distance between circles which is how I got the expression above. Apologies, I didn't write that in the description. Does that make sense?

Comment: notice that you read and update fx/fy in the same loop. This may result in interesting behaviors.
Moreover, variable 'dt' is actually 't'. It's not time difference between frames but rather a time when a specific frame takes place.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Code Review is for working code only, when you supply a link to code review, please direct the user to [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @tstanisl I see what you're saying, do you recommend making 2 separate loops instead or a different idea with some lines of code perhaps? And I can change the dt problem, thank you!